# Handling multiple network calls in a single service

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an AsyncTask in my Service so i can call multiple urls. I am not sure how i can handle calling urls in a single service. This is my current solution:

`public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String apiKey = preferences.getString("apiKey", null);
        FetchData data = new FetchData();
        data.execute("travel", apiKey);
        FetchData otherData = new FetchData();
        otherData.execute("notifications",apiKey);
        FetchData barData = new FetchData();
        barData.execute("bars", apiKey);
        checkData();
        return START_STICKY;
    }`

This is my ASyncTask doInBackgroud calling different urls:

```
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader= null;
        String data = null;


        try {
            selection = params[0];

            //url for the data fetch
            URL url = new URL("http://api.torn.com/user/?selections="+selection+"&key=*****");

            //gets the http result
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            //reads the data into an input file...maybe
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }

            //does something important
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            //reads the reader up above
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            data = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
```

how am not sure if i'm even supposed to use ASyncTask in a Service. Can anyone tell me what is the correct way of handle this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement an `AsyncTask`.  You should create a class that extends `Service`, this class will handle it's own message queue and create a separate thread for each message it receives.  For example:

```
public class MyNetworkService extends Service {
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Obtain your url from your data bundle, passed from the start intent.
            Bundle data = msg.getData();

            // Get your url string and api key.
            String action = data.getString("action");
            String apiKey = data.getString("apiKey");

            //
            //
            // Open your connection here.
            //
            //

            // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
            // the service in the middle of handling another job
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
                 Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Retrieve your bundle from your intent.
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();

        // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
        // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;

        // Set the message data as your intent bundle.
        msg.setData(data);

        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Once your service is set up, you can define that service in your manifest.

```
<service android:name=".MyNetworkService" />
```

In your activity, or wherever you feel it would be necessary, you can start the service using `startService()`, for example.

```
// Create the intent.
Intent travelServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MyNetworkService.class);

// Create the bundle to pass to the service.
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("action", "travel");
data.putString("apiKey", apiKey);

// Add the bundle to the intent.
travelServiceIntent.putExtras(data);

// Start the service.
startService(travelServiceIntent); // Call this for each URL connection you make.
```

If you want to bind the service and communicate with it from the UI thread, you need to implement an IBinder interface and call `bindService()` instead of `startService()`.

Check out [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Hope this helps.